Certiciate-signing-request (CSR) forwarding protocol
Is there is a standard protocol used to send generated CSR file (certificate-signing-request) and to receive the signed certificate? Or this communication depends on the CA / CMS instance that is specifically used?
Another question: what could be recommendation for simple Certificate Management Server to use that would serve these CSRs from multiple devices that need to refresh their certificates from time to time over the air? In my specific case these devices have preinstalled valid certificates which are needed to be replaced after certificates expiration.

There is ACME, but you're off topic here.
